# ObservableCollection, Polymorphism, Datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, polymorphism, observablecollection

Brief situation: I am trying to make a component reusuable by allowing client to supply the information to be displayed in a TabControl which contains the DataGrid.

Supposedly, client were to provide an `ObservableCollection<Product>` as one of the argument to be displayed in DataGrid. But in anycase:

Client may provide `ObservableCollection<SubProduct>` inherits Product class) class which  my component does not know of, which poses the following questions:

1) DataGrid does not autogenerate columns that SubProduct has not inherited from Product. Is there a way to work around it, that datagrid knows how to generate columns from a SubProduct, or even as far as given a super generic object type to bind to DataGrid eg: ObservableCollection.

I am only given a clue: What attributes (in strings) to be generated as columns. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to be sure: you want to make a user control that displays a datagrid which columns are auto generated by the properties of its items? I think I dont get it.

Comment: Obviously any property which is not inherited, how can that be shown on UI for that object. Even if you manually create dataGridColumn, it won't work since property is never a part of bound object.